# Show that if $v$ is orthogonal to both $w_1 $ and $w_2$ , then $v $is orthogonal to $k_1 w_1 + k_2 w_2 $ for all scalars $ k_1$ and $k_2 .$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

all i know is the formula for a unit vector u and to make the oppositely directed to v you make it -u... how do I show this problem?

Comment: You should probably learn the fact that two vectors are orthogonal iff their dot product is 0, and the fact that the dot product is a linear operation. Otherwise, you won't be able to do this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just elementary Linear Algebra, you can just show that since $v \cdot w_1 = 0$ and $v \cdot w_2 = 0$ Then,

$$  v \cdot (k_1w_1 +  k_2w_2) = k_1(v \cdot w_1) + k_2(v \cdot w_2) = 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

You can use properties of the inner product:

$$<kw_1+kw_2, v>=<kw_1,v>+<kw_2,v>=k<w_2,v>+ k<w_1,v> $$

Can you complete this?

Answer (score 1):

If two vectors are orthogonal you have $<u,v>=0$

So, you can use the properties of inner product to prove the above statement.